# Linking dll to c++ in qt for reading .mat files

Tags: qt, dll, linker, undefined-reference, mat

I am using Qt Creator 2.4.1(Based on Qt 4.7.4) ..
Now I want to open the .mat file which I got from Matlab.

I am using the basic function matOpen
Initially, I knew the headers required. They are mat.h, matrix.h and tmw.h.
Now, before running the code, I need to link the libraries. The required libraries as far as I know are libmat.dll and libmw.dll . I added them to the .pro file as follows.

```
QT       += core

QT       -= gui

TARGET = mat_open_test
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp

HEADERS += \
mat.h \
matrix.h \
tmwtypes.h

LIBS += -L"C:\Users\skanduri\Documents\C ++\mat_open_test-build-desktop-      Qt_4_8_1_for_Desktop_-_MinGW__Qt_SDK__Debug\debug\libmat.dll"

LIBS += -L"C:\Users\skanduri\Documents\C ++\mat_open_test-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_for_Desktop_-_MinGW__Qt_SDK__Debug\debug\libmx.dll"
```

Still I get error as : undefined reference to matOpen.. m sure the problem is with the linking.. But I dunno how to solve it. and the compiler Qt is using is MinGw .

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying library path only, not the libraries itself. Try

```
LIBS += -L"C:\Users\skanduri\Documents\C ++\mat_open_test-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_for_Desktop_-_MinGW__Qt_SDK__Debug\debug"
LIBS += -llibmx
LIBS += -llibmat
```